# How to obtain the condition of having non-trivial solution in this system?

Tags: systems-of-equations, determinant, fundamental-solution

I have a system of $2$ linear equations, with $4$ variables $\{a,b,c,d\}$

$$e^{-\frac{n}{2}} \left(5 a e^n-b n+b\right)-5 c n+3 d m=0,$$
$$e^{-\frac{1}{2} (n-4)} \left(3 b e^n-5 a\right)+5 c e^{m n}-3 d e^{-m n}=0$$

$m,n$ are positive parameters.

I want to find the condition under which the system is solvable. I mean I want to obtain the condition when the determinant of the matrix of coefficients is zero! But we know that the matrix of coefficients must be a squared-matrix to be able to calculate the determinant, but in this case, it is not.

How can I obtain the condition of the solvability of the system in such cases? Or in general, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, by "solvable" you mean that the system has a *non-zero* solution.  Your system is always solvable in this sense, because any system of linear equations in which the number of variables outnumbers the number of equations has a non-zero solution.  In your case, you can write your equations in the form of a matrix equation:
$$
\pmatrix{5e^{\frac{n}{2}}&-(n-1) e^{-\frac{n}{2}}&-5n&3m\\
-5e^{-\frac{(n-4)}{2}}&3e^{\frac{n+4}{2}}&5e^{mn}&-3e^{-mn}}\pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\d}=\pmatrix{0\\0}\ ,
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\pmatrix{5e^{\frac{n}{2}}&-(n-1) e^{-\frac{n}{2}}\\
-5e^{-\frac{(n-4)}{2}}&3e^{\frac{n+4}{2}}}\pmatrix{a\\b}= \pmatrix{5n&-3m\\-5e^{mn}&3e^{-mn}}\pmatrix{c\\d}\ .
$$
The $\ 2\times2\ $ matrix on the left side of this last equation has determinant
$$
5\left(3e^{n+2}-(n-1)e^{2-n}\right)=5e^{2-n}\left(3e^{2n}+1-n\right)
$$
which is strictly positive for all values of $\ n\ $.  The matrix is therefore nonsingular, and you can solve the system by choosing $\ c\ $ and $\ d\ $ to have any values you please, and then solving the equations above to obtain $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ in terms of $\ c\ $ and $\ d\ $.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain how you obtained the last equation? which $4\times4$ matrix did you mean? I see a $2\times2$ matrix. And, why the determinants of the lhs and rhs of your second equation must be equal? And where is the parameter $m$ in the last answer?

Comment: Yes, you're right; it's a $\ 2\times2\ $ matrix, not $\ 4\times4\ $. Apologies for that blunder.  The determinant of the matrix on right hand side doesn't have to be the same as that of the one on the left.  Both sides of the very last equation are the determinant of the matrix on the *left* hand side of the preceding equation, just written slightly differently to make it clear that the expression is always positive.  The parameter $\ m\ $ doesn't appear in that determinant because it doesn't appear in the matrix on the left, only in the one on the right.